# HTML found in code but not visible after ajax load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm using `$.get` to load the content from a page 2 div (`oldDiv`) and add it to a div (`newDiv`) next to a `section` of page 1, most of the HTML loads without issues, even a third-party widget with script attached loads fully, but there's one particular div (a form) that even when it's visible through Inspect Element and I can even use it by finding the fields with the cursor and sending my info, I can't actually SEE it.

The space is there, and I can even alter things like padding and margin and see the space around it change, but I can't see it!

It's driving me insane and I don't know what the problem is.

Here's the code:

```
$("section").first().after('<div class="newDiv"></div>');

$(function() {
  $.get('/page2', function(result){
    $result = $(result);
    $result.find('.oldDiv').appendTo('.newDiv');
    $result.find('script').appendTo('.newDiv');
  }, 'html');
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the newDiv html to the question?

Comment: Verify whether your element is hidden with css, maybe your form has opacity 0 or display none when added to that dom.

Comment: Sounds like could be visibility:hidden or the opacity is set to 0... Possible that something is setting CSS on that element? Display:none would remove it from the flow, you wouldn't be able to see the margin/padding around it.

Comment: I'm kicking myself right now, I can't believe I didn't try with opacity. That was the issue. Thank you!